# Best recording set up for student work

Tags: student, outdoor, cheap

Hi all,

I'm a sound production student and i'm looking into doing quite a lot of loud effects recordings i.e car tyre screeching, engine recordings aswell as some outdoor speech recordings and crowd "walla". I'd like the ability to record a wide range of volumes without being to specific to one set up, if you get me! I'm now in the market for a suitable set up (on a student budget) that could perform well over all.

I have access to some Zoom portable recorders but id really like to get myself a decent kit that could be used in more situations. 
Along what lines should I be looking and what prices should I expect to pay?

Appologies for any newb questions, and thanks for any help in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NickMcK

I suggest getting a dedicated field recorder e.g. Fostex FR2-LE. Very inexpensive and blows handheld recorders out of the water. And you can continue using it by just changing the mics you connect to it. Some might suggest something like the Zoom H4N, but for me all the handheld recorders have too many compromises for good quality and low-noise sound recording.

Pair it with microphone(s) in your budget. Rode NTG-2 is a fairly good and inexpensive shotgun mic. Rode NT3 is a good basic cardioid field condenser. For stereo recording you should look at Rode NT4, Rode NT5 pair or e.g. Oktava MK-012 pair, but there are probably a dozen other options as well like MXL V67N (very inexpensive SDC). You also need some sort of wind protection (go with the furry ones instead of basic foam ones), but probably could do with normal mic stands or some very inexpensive pistol grip depending on your preference.

Look to spend at least 500€ for the whole setup. Buy used equipment if you can find some.

Comment: Although Utopia has made some great points about using a handheld too, which I concur.  The bigger rigs are great, but there just some things that you can only get with having an additional handheld recorder at your side (even more pertinent nowadays because of all the 'neighborhood watch' nature of our society where everything is deemed suspicious and questionable, especially recording devices)